# Can't acces innerHTML property of an img element

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I'm doing an exercise from udacity's javascript desing patterns. We were told to make a page that had pictures of cats, their names, and counters that increment every time we click on a cat's picture. I managed to do that as you can see in my code, with a forloop that added event listeners to each image.
After we did that, they told us that we had to change it. Now we had to make a list or index with each cat's name, and when we clicked in any of the names, that cat's picture should appear somwhere on the page, along with its name and counter. My problem comes when I try to access the innerHTML of the image elements with the forloop in order to add those to "mylist". Nothing happens when I write that part of the code, and if I use the forEach to make a property containing the innerhtml in order to put that property (object.name for example) in the list elements in html, it makes a list that shows "undefined" instead of the innerHTML that I want it to show (the cat's name). That means there's something wrong with the html objects contained in the listOfImages array. What do I have to do? Is there any smarter aproach to do this? Why can't I access the img's innerHTML? thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
 <title>Cat clicker!</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<style type="text/css">
 * {
  margin: 20;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 body {
  background: white;
 }
</style>

<body>
<div class = "container">
 <h1><i><b>Gatitos</b></i></h1>
 <br>
 <br>
</div>

 <div id = 0><img src="cat1.jpg" id = 0 width = 470 height = 340><h1 style = "color:red">Lucas</h1></div>

 <div id = 1><img src="cat2.jpg" id = 1 width = 470 height = 340><h1 style = "color:red">Martin</h1></div>

 <div id = 2><img src="cat3.jpg" id = 2 width = 470 height = 340><h1 style = "color:red">Pedro</h1></div>

 <div id = 3><img src="cat4.jpg" id = 3 width = 470 height = 340><h1 style = "color:red">Felix</h1></div>

 <div id = 4><img src="cat5.jpg" id = 4 width = 470 height = 340><h1 style = "color:red">Felipe</h1></div>


<div>
 <ul id = "namesList">
  <!-- here i'd like to add the innerHTMLs of each img tag -->
 </ul>
</div>





<script type="text/javascript">

 var listOfImages = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("img"));

 var listOfCounters = [];



 //this forloop creates a counter for each image and appends that counter to a list of h1 counter elements
 for (var i = 0; i<listOfImages.length; i++){

  //adds the links to the list
  var catName = document.createElement("h2");
  var catNameText = document.createTextNode(listOfImages[i].innerHTML);
  catName.appendChild(catNameText);
  document.getElementById("namesList").appendChild(catName);

 
  //adds the counter to each image 
  var h1 = document.createElement("h1");        
  var t = document.createTextNode(0);       
  h1.appendChild(t);                                
  document.getElementById(i).appendChild(h1);  
  
  //adds the counter to the list of counters 
  listOfCounters.push(h1);  
 };
 
 //adds the counters objects as properties of each image element, and then adds click listeners to each image, in order to update each counter 
 listOfImages.forEach(function(element, index){
  var count = 0;
  element.nombre = element.innerHTML;
  element.counter = listOfCounters[index];
  element.addEventListener("click", function(){
   element.counter.innerHTML = count +1;
   count += 1;
  });
 });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the `img` element has no concept of `innerHTML`

Comment: @DacreDenny and how do I acces the text inside the img element? do I have to use the innerHTML of the h1 that I put inside the img element?

Comment: `img` elements can't have anything inside of them, but you can access the innerHTML of the `h1` elements that are adjacent to the `img` elements

Comment: Also worth noting `id` must be unique on the page. You should also enclose attributes with quotes.

Comment: Think about it this way, your `h1` tags are siblings to the `img` tag, not a child (or innerHtml) of the `img` tag. The `img` tag is self closed as can optionally be denoted as `<img src="cat1.jpg" id="0" width="470" height="340"/>`

Answer (score 2):

`innerHtml` allows you to access and modify html data that are **inside** a tag.

For the case of `<img />`, which is a single tag, it cannot contain any data inside it.

If you wish to access the attributes of the image instead, may be you can use

```
listOfImages[i].getAttribute(your desired attribute)
```

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out, `<img/>` tags are self-closing, meaning they have no inner content.

What I would suggest in this case is to traverse up to the parent `<div>` element (via `parentNode`) and get its `textContent`. This will contain only the text of the `<div>` and any child elements.

For example...

```js
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(img => {
  let text = img.parentNode.textContent
  console.info(img.id, img.getAttribute('src'), text)
})
```

```css
div {display: none;}
```

```html
<div id=0><img src="cat1.jpg" id=0 width=4 70 height=3 40><h1 style="color:red">Lucas</h1></div><div id=1><img src="cat2.jpg" id=1 width=4 70 height=3 40><h1 style="color:red">Martin</h1></div><div id=2><img src="cat3.jpg" id=2 width=4 70 height=3 40><h1 style="color:red">Pedro</h1></div><div id=3><img src="cat4.jpg" id=3 width=4 70 height=3 40><h1 style="color:red">Felix</h1></div><div id=4><img src="cat5.jpg" id=4 width=4 70 height=3 40><h1 style="color:red">Felipe</h1></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: I used class attributes in the headers I wanted to display in my list of names. That way, I could use querySelectorAll(".classname") in order to get all those headers with the classname I had set. Thank y'all

```
<div hidden id = 0><img src="cat1.jpg" id = 0 width = 470 height = 340><h1 class = "names" style = "color:red">Lucas</h1></div>
```

and then

```
var listOfNames = document.querySelectorAll(".names");
```

that way I could access those elements' innerHTML 
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have addressed why `img` has no `innerHtml`, I'll answer the question of is there is a better way.

One of the cleaner ways is to dispose of what you have done so far and more-or-less start again.

We'll use css to hide and display the images are just use JavaScript to keep track of the click count using a `data-attribute`

```js
var links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".cats a"));
var countTarget = document.getElementById("count");

links.forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    //Get count from the data attribute and increment it
    var count = parseInt(this.dataset.clicks, 10) + 1;
    //Display it
    countTarget.innerHTML = this.innerText + " count: " + count;
    //Update data attribute
    this.dataset.clicks = count;
  })
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 20;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: white;
}


/*Our links and images will be set relative to this*/

.cats {
  position: relative;
}

.cats>ul {
  /*Limit the with of the links*/
  width: 50%;
  /*Reset list styles*/
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  /*Add some style*/
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/*Style the links*/
.cats>ul a:link,
.cats>ul a:visited {
  color: #F00;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*Position our images relative to the outer div*/
/*and hide them by default*/
.cats img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
}

/*Display the image with the id in the link*/
.cats img:target {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1><i><b>Gatitos</b></i></h1>
</div>
<div class="cats">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#phill" data-clicks="0">Phill</a><img id="phill" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/470/300"></li>
    <li><a href="#nick" data-clicks="0">Nicky</a><img id="nick" src="https://www.placecage.com/470/300"></li>
    <li><a href="#mittens" data-clicks="0">Mittens</a><img id="mittens" src="http://placekitten.com/470/300"></li>
    <li><a href="#funky" data-clicks="0">Funky</a><img id="funky" src="https://www.placecage.com/gif/470/300"></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="count"></div>
</div>
```